# Using SetInterval in React ComponentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

am bit struggling with introducing react class componentDidUpdate with setInterval

my code look like this

```
 componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    const data = this.props.fullData;
    if (prevProps.fullData !== this.props.fullData) {
      this.setState({
        mediaAllData: data.ALL ? data.ALL : [],
      });

      const wholeAssets = data.ALL ? data.ALL : [];
      const assetsWithIncomplete = wholeAssets.filter(
        i => i.status === '6',
      );
      if(assetsWithIncomplete.length>0){
         // need to call api with list of id's whose status is 6. Here for example [1,2,3]
    }
```

This code will work on initial page load
And if wholeAssets length is greater than 0 , i need to call API and check the status of individual data .
Normally after 7 seconds , it update status.So how can i check the same with setInterval in ComponentDidUpdate.
And the api should **stop** trigger api , if none of individual data have status 6.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.
My guess is you are trying to poll.

But `setInterval` would not wait for the response, use a `setTimeout` that checks for the response and only then fires.

Comment: @UtsavPatel i need to call this info api after each 7 seconds , till the status becomes 8. Once all got status 8, should clear the interval

Comment: @UtsavPatel initailly am calling whole list , which comes with whole data with many of them having status 8 , which is fine, but for those who do have status 6, i need to call after each seconds and update with whole, may be after some might get status updates to 8 , but there will be still some with status 6. This interval should fire api till all got status 8

Comment: Can you include the code for the API call, and the code for the interval you're trying to setup?

Comment: @DrewReese :i had added the check . if assetsWithIncomplete.length>0  then it will be taking the id,s whose status is 6 and will send to backend to check , if status got reflected or not . if all got status 8 , then i should clear this interval. i dont want the api to tirgger again , or if some got 8 and some still 6 , it need to fire api till all status becomes 8

Comment: I see, so if you're missing some data you want to setup some polling to hit some status endpoint until all data is received, and at that point quit polling?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, you are right

Comment: I'd suggest a better way to handle this would be setting up this call with `GET` of the previous call where your data is initially received. Only when your dataset is complete, you pass it to your ccomponent. @midhunk

Comment: However, if you still wanna go ahead with your approach, you might want to do something like this:
`var setIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
  chekWithAPICall().then((res)=>{
    if(res.success){
      clearInterval(setIntervalId);
}
})
}, 7000);`

Comment: Ok, so basically you'll want two functions, one to start interval/timer to queue up array of status requests (expires and check status and restart), as statuses resolve update state (and possible restart in `componentDidUpdate`), the other to terminate all timers. When statuses are updated and flow lands back in `componentDidUpdate` kill running timers and recheck.

Comment: @DrewReese -i think you are correct

Comment: @RahulDwivedi i am writing API functions in reducer, so i cant use . then function in component

Comment: @midhunk you mean in `actions`? That's why I previously suggested you can call this API which basically 'completes' your `dataset` at the time when you're receiving the initial data. For e.g, 

`fetchInitialData.then((res)=>{if(res.success){CompleteMyResultSet().then(res)=>{//Pass it to reducers and subsequently to component}}})`

Comment: @RahulDwivedi we cant wait like that.. it will be 100 of items. and we will display 100 items. but for item if status is not 8 means we will disbale the item, but user can see . and it will be around 2,3 items maximum. and after some time, it may become 8 and user can see all items with enabled

Comment: Alright, then let's do like this:

`const setIntervaId = setInterval(()=>{
    //setup a state in your reducer with myDataSetComplete: false, and set it up in
    //your set state to props as well
    if(this.props.myDataSetComplete){
      clearInterval(setIntervaId)
    }else{
      //Set up in map dispatch to props
      this.props.CallAnotherAPIToCompleteMyDataset();
    }
     
  }, 7000)`

Comment: @midhunk See this formatted properly in the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we do something like this>:

```
if(assetsWithIncomplete.length>0){

  let setIntervaId = setInterval(()=>{
    //setup a state in your reducer with myDataSetComplete: false, and set it up in
    //your set state to props as well
    if(this.props.myDataSetComplete){
      clearInterval(setIntervaId)
    }else{
      //Set up in map dispatch to props
      this.props.CallAnotherAPIToCompleteMyDataset(val);
    }

  }, 7000)
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {

  return {
    .....,
    myDataSetComplete: state.myDataSetComplete
  };
};

const mapDispachToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
  return {
    .....,
   CallAnotherAPIToCompleteMyDataset: (val) => dispatch(actionCreators.CallAnotherAPIToCompleteMyDataset(val)),
  };
};
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    .....,
    myDataSetComplete: false
};
```

Comment: i understood your solution. but when we will make  myDataSetComplete to true, then only it will clear interval right ? also i need to update the new Data with setState as well

Comment: Yup absolutely. And we'll set `myDataSetComplete ` to true in our `reducer` once the set is complete.

Comment: on else part of this if(assetsWithIncomplete.length>0){ i need to make  myDataSetComplete to true ,right ? then only it will clear interval ,right ?

Comment: This whole `setInterval` stuff will be called only when `if(assetsWithIncomplete.length>0)`. You need to make `myDataSetComplete` to `true` in your reducer. Once you put these code on your editor and try, you'll get the whole idea.

Comment: correct me if am wrong, on what scenario i should make  myDataSetComplete to true ? as initial State its false. Also when i get response from  CallAnotherAPIToCompleteMyDataset ,it should check the reponse right ? here the CallAnotherAPIToCompleteMyDataset keeps on calling after 7 seconds ? u got what am saying ?

Comment: if(assetsWithIncomplete.length>0){ } this condition should come with in setINTERVAL RIGHT ? Because in each 7 seconds i should check whether the length > 0. if length >0 , then only we should fire the api

Comment: @midhunk So here what you need to is just this, once you receive the response of `CallAnotherAPIToCompleteMyDataset `, you''ll set `myDataSetComplete ` in your reducer to `true`. Post that, the  `clearInterval(setIntervaId)` will be called and your `CallAnotherAPIToCompleteMyDataset` will not be called again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213987/discussion-between-midhun-k-and-rahul-dwivedi).